# Delphi - How to get WrapText to behave like RichEdit.Lines.Text?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, word-wrap

I use TRichEdit to edit text. I have WordWrap turned on which automatically wraps text at the edge of control so that there are no scroll-bars. RichEdit width is set to fit 80 columns.

WordWrap simulates this behaviour nicely as long as you have occasional space between words. But if you have a very loooooooooooooooooong word RichEdit wrap will break it automatically and WordWrap won't!

If I want now to access these wrapped lines I can get it through `RichEdit.Lines.Text` which will put automatically CRLF at column 80. If I use RichEdit.Text I get raw text with no CRLF suitable for WordWrap.

The task is not trivial to do in a custom function as I already tried and it was not a small function but might there be a way to use wrapping functions of TRichEdit? I have an idea to create hidden RichEdit but that kind of seems stupid for this task as I would have to calculate its width just to do wordwrapping - rather pointless I think.

The question - is there a way to force WordWrap to cut long words that cannot be wrapped otherwise? So if a word is 170 characters long, it would be wrapped into 3 lines 80 + 80 + 10 but also taking care of words before to fill previous and following lines?

Comment: 80 characters is what you want? Or do you care about variable width fonts?

Comment: I need a fixed-width column 80 (or any other) wrap. If over column 80, cut and wrap to another row. If too long, cut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on for size:

```
procedure TForm1.RichEdit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
const
   MAX_LENGTH = 80;
var
  nLineCount:   integer;
  sCurrentLine: string;
begin
  for nLineCount := 0 to RichEdit1.Lines.Count - 1 do
  begin
    // no space in this line
    if (pos(' ',RichEdit1.Lines.Strings[nLineCount]) = 0) then
    begin
      if (length(RichEdit1.Lines.Strings[nLineCount]) > MAX_LENGTH) then
      begin
        // hold the whole line
        sCurrentLine := RichEdit1.Lines.Strings[nLineCount];
        // the current line, make the max value
        RichEdit1.Lines.Strings[nLineCount] := copy(sCurrentLine,1,MAX_LENGTH);
        // build the next line
        RichEdit1.Lines.Add(
        copy(sCurrentLine,MAX_LENGTH + 1,1));
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I can't use this because I need to reformat text after it has been typed in not during typing. RichEdit.Lines.Text already does this when WordWrap is turned on without any code. Thanks for the answer though but I need to wait if anyone comes up with different solution.